# WPF C# - Add 3 string to DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm currently making a Launcher (Imagine something like the LoL launcher) for my Source Engine based game.

I have a working SSQLib that query the server data (Server name, Currentplayers/Maxplayers, Map name). I want to list these three data in a DataGrid. So, how can I list these in a DataGrid?

Here's my code:

```
private void btnLoadDataGrid_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string ip = "192.168.1.73";
            int port = 27015;

            IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);

            SSQL query = new SSQL();
            ServerInfo serverInformation = query.Server(endpoint);

            string servername = serverInformation.Name.ToString();
            string mapname = serverInformation.Map.ToString();
            string servermaxplayer = serverInformation.MaxPlayers.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use MVVMC and I understand correctly what you try to do, your code should look similar to the following:

View:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid"   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyObservableCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ServerName" Binding="{Binding servername}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="MapName" Binding="{Binding mapname}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="MaxPlayers" Binding="{Binding servermaxplayer}"/>               
            </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

ViewModel:

```
private ObservableCollection<ServerModel> _myObservableCollection;

        public ObservableCollection<ServerModel> MyObservableCollection
        {
            get { return _myObservableCollection; }
            set
            {
                if (_myObservableCollection == value)                                
                    return;
                _myObservableCollection = value;                                     
                OnPropertyChanged("MyObservableCollection");                         
            }
        }
```

Controller:

```
private LauncherViewModel mViewModel;             

        public void Initialize()                                          
        {
            var view = new Launcher();

            mViewModel = new LauncherViewModel
            {
                MyObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<ServerModel>(),
            };
            view.DataContext = mViewModel;
            view.ShowDialog();

        }
```

Model:

```
public class ServerModel

public string servername { get; set; }
public string mapname { get; set; }
public int servermaxplayer { get; set; }
```

Additionally, you should define the servermaxplayer Property as an int, because it is a number, not a string --> see Model. :)

Comment: was my pleasure :)